# Change itemize symbol in a Beamer note

Tags: beamer, itemize

I'd like to change the symbols used for itemize lists inside `beamer` notes. Setting for example `\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[triangle]` affects only my itemize lists outside of notes (besides the styles for those outside are different than for those in notes).

How can I change the symbols used for itemize lists inside notes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could include the following commands in the preamble:

```
\AtBeginNote{\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[triangle] \par}
\AtEndNote{\par}
```

(The `\par` commands are there to make sure that there's no unwanted run-in from the preceding text into the note text, and vice versa.)

Comment: What if I have to change the symbols multiple times in a presentation? Now I use `{enumerate}` package to do it. But every time I do not put in a number such as in `\begin{enumerate}[$\bullet$]`, I get annoying warning "the counter will not be printed". What do you suggest me to do then?

Comment: @TroyWoo - I'm afraid I don't fully understand your objective. Please consider posting a new query that lays our your goals.

Answer (score 0):

I guess with `beamer` note you mean the article, or? If yes, it is fairly easy: Just redefine the symbol in the corresponding \mode block.

```
\mode<article>{%
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{+}%
}
\mode<presentation>{\usetheme{Berlin}}
```

A while ago I have created an example showing how to create both, article and slides, in one document, have a look at: http://uweziegenhagen.de/?p=1053. I used the above command with this example.

Uwe

Comment: In `beamer`, "notes" are (usually) things that are meant to show up on the presenter's own screen (e.g., on his/her laptop) but not on the main screen that the audience gets to see. See Section 19 of the manual, "Adding notes for yourself."